# Can I conditionally expand/collapse a Section in my Workshop App based on whether another section is expanded/collapsed?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have a Workshop App with two sections that involve two different workflows. The user will only be working in one section at a time and I want to free up more screen space by collapsing the unused section. Is there a way to automatically expand/collapse one section based on the expanded/collapsed state of the other section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native way to do this, but you can achieve it by creating a `Button Group` widget and adding events that `Toggle` the sections:

[image]

In your Section configs you can set which Section is expanded initially (Here Section 1 is open initially and section two is not):

[image]

So when you open your app in viewing mode it looks like this:

[image]

And after clicking the `Section Toggle` button:

[image]